# [AVRetainReleaseWeakReference release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x171a2cd40

Tags: objective-c, ios8, avfoundation, hardware-acceleration

[Screencap of the stack when crash happened][1]

This happened after:

[self.sampleBufferDisplayLayer stopRequestingMediaData]; [self.sampleBufferDisplayLayer removeFromSuperlayer];

while the address of self.sampleBufferDisplayLayer is 0x171a2d040; Is it means that the instance(0x171a2cd40) which has been deallocated for twice is something inside the AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer object? Then why should I be responsible for the twice dealloc error of this inside object? Does someone ever suffer from this?

```
0   libsystem_malloc.dylib   0x0000000196cbd9cc 0x196cb8000 + 22988
1   TTKanKan                 0x00000001008733b8 0x1000e0000 + 7943096
2   TTKanKan                 0x0000000100864584 0x1000e0000 + 7882116
3   TTKanKan                 0x000000010085f1e0 0x1000e0000 + 7860704
4   TTKanKan                 0x000000010085f36c 0x1000e0000 + 7861100
5   TTKanKan                 0x000000010085edd4 0x1000e0000 + 7859668
6   TTKanKan                 0x000000010085f7b8 0x1000e0000 + 7862200
7   TTKanKan                 0x000000010085f5fc 0x1000e0000 + 7861756
8   TTKanKan                 0x000000010085ef3c 0x1000e0000 + 7860028
9   TTKanKan                 0x000000010085ecac 0x1000e0000 + 7859372
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib  0x0000000196d2bdb4 _pthread_body + 160
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib  0x0000000196d2bd10 _pthread_start + 156
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib  0x0000000196d28ee4 thread_start + 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fix it by remove the same deallocation and allocation of AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer in another thread， although I  had use @synchronized(self) to synchronize them in different thread. And now deallocation and allocation of AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer only occur in one thread.

Comment: I also encountered that. My app started crashing after IOS9(something) and it seams like instead of returning 'nil' or doing 'nil' on the 'nil-object'(AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer) the app crashes instead. It's against all the Objective-C rules I know (Even try/catch did not prevent the app from a crash).